# How to get a non generic cast method information?

Tags: generics, reflection, casting, c#-2.0

We have a legacy application that has a class like this :

```
public class Person
{
private PersonType _type;

public PersonType GetPersonType()
{
return _type;
}
}
```

PersonType is a base class of several person types (User,Customer and ...)

so every time we want to get the type to do something with it we should cast it like this :

```
var userType=(User)Person.GetPersonType();
```

Then I thought maybe we can have a generic overload like this :

```
var userType=Person.GetPersonType<User>();
```

So I added the overloaded method to class. Later I found out that there's another code that uses reflection to get the first method :

```
var methodInfo=person.GetType().GetMethod("GetPersonType");
```

but since I have added this overload we are getting an ambiguous method exception.I tried to find a way to somehow distinguish the exact overload that I was looking for with no success.
So the question is how we can o get the non-generic overload info ?
(As I said it's a legacy app built using framework 2 and we can't use Linq and\or Extensions.)

Comment: What is the value of your generic method, vs the cast?  Seems to me that you should remove the generic method.

Comment: We have line of codes that are full of parenthesis because of nested casts . I wanted to make the code more readable.for example ((User)Person.GetPersonType()).Title="Somthing" vs. Person.GetPersonType<User>().Title="Something"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell which method is the first non-generic one like this:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = person.GetType().GetMethods();
foreach (MethodInfo mi in methods)
    if (mi.Name == "GetPersonType" && !mi.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
        return mi;
```

Comment: You mean there's not anyway so we can tell which method is which ?

Comment: Apologize, had come back to the post after a while and had forgotten that part

Comment: NP.  Fixed a few bugs I had in there too.